# Pointwise convergence of $x^n$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am reading a book where they state that $f_n(x) = x^n$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = \chi_{\{1\}}(x)$ with respect to the norm $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ and two pages later they state that it doesn't with respect to the same norm. Here are the relevant parts:

Edited: A user mentioned that images are frowned upon, so I tried rewriting everything that was in the images word for word (I was not sure how to rewrite some math in mathjax so I tried using what I believe is an equivalent way to rewrite it (the images are left for reference if anybody notices anything that I haven't rewritten correctly, and obviously the figure which I have no way of recreating in text):

> Example 2.4 Let us consider a real-valued sequence of functions, $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$, with $f_n(x) = x^n \in C[0,1]$. With respect to the $\textit{supremum norm}$, defined by:
>   $$||f_n||_{\infty} := \sup_{x\in[0,1]}{|f_n(x)|},$$ 
>   the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ converges pointwise to the limit function $f$, given by, $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x=1$, as it holds:
>   $$||f_n(x)-f(x)||_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in[0,1)}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|} = |x^n|<\epsilon$$
>
> for all $x \in [0,1)$, and $||f_n(1)-1||_{\infty} = 0$.
>   From this observation we can conclude: $f_n$ converges pointwise with respect to
>   the supremum norm $||f_n||_{\infty}$, towards the limit function f that takes the value zero in the half-open interval $[0, 1)$ and is exactly one for $x = 1$. Obviously, the sequence $f_n$ converges towards a discontinuous function, that is, the limit function is not a $C[0, 1]$ member of the space $C[0, 1]$, see Figure 2.4:
>
> [image: Figure 2.4]

The text below the figure above reads:

> FIGURE 2.4: POINTWISE AND UNIFORM CONVERGENCE. Elements of the sequences of
>   functions $f_n = x^n$ and $g_n = \frac{2x}{1+n^2x^2}$ . Obviously, $f_n$ is pointwise convergent to $0$ in the interval $[0, 1)$, but neither pointwise nor uniformly convergent on the closed interval $[0, 1]$. The sequence $g_n$ is uniformly convergent towards $0$ on $[0, 1]$ with respect to the infinity norm.

Two pages after example 2.4, one can find example 2.5:

> EXAMPLE 2.5 Let us consider once more the sequence of functions from Example 2.4.
>   As we have seen, $f_n$ converges with respect to the supremum norm pointwise to a limit function. With respect to the supremum norm, defined by,
>   $$||f_n||_{\infty} := \sup_{x\in[0,1]}{|f_n(x)|},$$ 
>   the sequence of functions is not convergent to the limit function $f(x)$ since it holds:
>   $$||f_n-f||_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|} = 1$$
>   As this example shows, in infinite-dimensional linear spaces convergence defined by a certain norm can be stronger than by another norm.

I've left the images just for reference: [Example 2.4 Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuF16.png), [Example 2.4 Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHwSx.png), [Example 2.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPUhh.png)

Can anyone guess what the norm was supposed to be in the second case for $f_n$ to not converge pointwise? Will just changing the interval for the supremum do anything?

From here on are extra edits that were not present in my original post that are meant to address some of the things that we discussed in the comments:

From what I gather Example 2.4 refers to pointwise convergence, and Example 2.5 refers to uniform convergence, but why is then this part emphasized:
"As this example shows, in infinite-dimensional linear spaces convergence defined by a certain norm can be stronger than by another norm."
As far as I can see the norms used in 2.4 and 2.5 are identical, or at least the initial definition in the text is identical, but they go onto prove pointwise vs uniform convergence?
I also assume based on the conversations in the comments that the statement "Obviously, $f_n$ is pointwise convergent to $0$ in the interval $[0, 1)$, but neither pointwise nor uniformly convergent on the closed interval $[0, 1]$." in Figure 2.4. is incorrect, as the sequence is actually pointwise convergent in $[0,1]$ but not uniformly.

Finally a lot of people have mentioned that the "pointwise convergence wrt a norm" doesn't make sense. But here's the definition of pointwise convergence that I have from the same book, which clearly uses the norm of the space (which in the example just happened to be the infinity norm):

> DEFINITION 2.3 (Pointwise Convergence) A sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of functions of a linear normed function space $(S, ||\cdot||)$ is said to converge pointwise to the limit function f, in sign $f_n \rightarrow f$, if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $N(\epsilon, x)$, depending on $x$ and $\epsilon$, such that it holds:
>   $$||f_n(x)-f(x)|| < \epsilon$$
>   for all $n>N(\epsilon,x)$ and $x\in Dom(f)$.

For completeness the image of this: [Definition 2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvlMn.png)

The way I see it, they take the normed space $(C[0,1],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ and take the sequence $f_n(x) = x^n$ from it, then they show that it is pointwise convergent to $f(x) \not\in C[0,1]$ with respect to the norm of the space. I don't get which part of this does not make sense. Is the definition of pointwise convergence wrong in the book that I am reading, since it is defined with respect to the norm of the space? What norm should it be defined with respect to then?

Also if the text is indeed "too sloppy", I would by happy for any recommendations with which to complement my reading (the book is not specifically on functional analysis so I cannot substitute it entirely with a functional analysis book, it simply uses certain statements from it).

Edit 2:
I realized what the issue was thanks to the answer, I believe that the author wanted to use the $|\cdot|$ norm for the first example, in which case his proof would have worked. And then Figure 2.4 makes sense, and example 2.5 also makes sense.

Comment: This seems to be an exceedingly sloppy text. How does it hold that $|x^n|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1)$? Of course, they're *fixing* $x$ and letting $n\to\infty$ and not saying any of that. In the second example, they're *varying* $x$ and deducing that the convergence is *not* uniform on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @TedShifrin so "the difference in the norm" is really the fact that they are checking for uniform convergence in the second case? I was thinking something along those lines, but I got hit with that: https://imgur.com/dZFjndD

Comment: (2.9) is wrong. There $x$ is fixed. And then they don't say $|x^n|<\epsilon$ holds for $n\ge N$ for some appropriately chosen $N$. I would not read this text without lots and lots of red ink.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say 'converges pointwise' with respect to some norm. 2.9 is just flat-out wrong. If a sequence of continuous functions converges with the $\sup$ norm then the limit is also continuous.

Comment: I believe they were going for something along those lines in 2.9: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punktweise_Konvergenz#Beispiel

Comment: @copper.hat Why would saying "converges pointwise wrt some norm" not make sense? Isn't convergence dependent on the norm?

Comment: @lightxbulb: Because pointwise convergence is not with respect to anything. It is pointwise, independently of any norm.

Comment: @copper.hat Doesn't the norm used in $||f_n(x)-f(x)||<\epsilon, n>N(\epsilon,x)$ matter? What if $f_n$ are vector valued?

Comment: @lightxbulb: I'm not sure what you are asking. In the above, pointwise means $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$ (however you decide that  $f_n(x) \to f(x)$, in the above it means $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$). It has nothing to do with the norm on the function whatsoever.

Comment: @copper.hat This is how they define pointwise convergence in the text that I am reading: https://imgur.com/Vmc3OeG
The norm of the space is used for the convergence. You're using an absolute value since I think you're assuming the range of $f$ is a subset of the real numbers, however the text works with arbitrary abstract linear normed function spaces.

Comment: @lightxbulb: I think we are beating this to death. There is some distance used for determining how close $f(x)$ and $f_n(x)$ are, and there is some distance used for determining how close $f$ and $f_n$ are. When one talks about pointwise convergence they are referring to the first, which has nothing to do with the second.

Comment: @copper.hat In the first case it's still with respect to that "distance" - which in this case is your norm. Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that means that "pointwise convergence with respect to some norm" makes sense. Even in the 1D real line case the absolute value and the supremum norm convergence differ.

Comment: @TedShifrin Would you recommend any detailed reference that I could use to sanity check statements from this book that I am not sure about (it's not specifically on functional analysis, so I can't really substitute it for another book, but I can at least refer to something better for the parts that coincide).

Comment: Take $\varepsilon=\frac1{2}$. For each fixed positive integer $n>1$, we have $x_n:=(1-\frac1{n})^{\frac{1}n} \in [0,1)$ but $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|=1-\frac1{n}\geq \varepsilon$. As others have noted, bringing up the $\sup$-norm in example 2.4 just confuses things.

Comment: @MattAPelto You're proving that it is not uniformly convergent right? But it should be pointwise convergent? So this is incorrect:  imgur.com/dZFjndD  
The first statement on pointwise convergence is correct, and the last regarding uniform convergence is also correct, but the one for the figure in the link is incorrect. Did I get everything right? Any reference you would recommend that I can use along with this book?

Comment: The only error I see in the image is stating that $f_n$ doesn't converge pointwise on $[0,1]$ (I mean unless it means to say doesn't converge pointwise to $h \equiv 0$). My comment was meant to highlight how we interpret $\sup_{x \in [0,1)} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ - $x$ is not fixed when we take the supremum here.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I edited it, thanks for mentioning this, I wasn't aware of this fact.

Comment: I've converted my downvote to upvote, thanks to your consideration of the visually impaired and users of [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz), which is a search engine using MathJax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question has been answered in comments, and the conclusion is that the text doesn't make any sense. Quotation: "With respect to the supremum-norm the sequence converges pointwise".

1. Yes, it converges pointwise.
2. Convergence with respect to the supremum-norm trivially implies pointwise convergence.
3. Pointwise convergence is much weaker than norm-convergence.
4. The statement "With respect to the supremum-norm the sequence converges pointwise" is complete rubbish.

Edited:

Convergence in $C([0,1])$ with respect to the supremum-norm $\lVert - \rVert_\infty$ is nothing else than uniform convergence. The (uniform) limit of a sequence $(f_n)$, if it exists, is again a function in $C([0,1])$. You see that $(x^n)$ has a pointwise limit which is not continuous at the point $x = 1$, hence the convergence cannot be uniform.

Consider the definition
$$||g||_{\infty} := \sup_{x\in[0,1]}{|g(x)|}$$
for $g \in C([0,1])$. It does not make any sense to write

"The sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ converges pointwise to the limit function $f$, given by, $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x=1$, as it holds:
$$||f_n(x)-f(x)||_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in[0,1)}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|} = |x^n|<\epsilon$$
for all $x \in [0,1)$, and $||f_n(1)-1||_{\infty} = 0$."

The notation $||f_n(x)-f(x)||_{\infty}$ is meaningless. Moreover, it is not true that $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|} <\epsilon$ unless $\epsilon > 1$. In fact, for each $n$ you have $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|} = \sup_{x\in[0,1)}{|x^n|} = 1$.

The correct approach is to replace $||f_n(x)-f(x)||_{\infty}$ by  $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$. Then for $x \in [0,1)$ you get correctly $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |x^n| < \epsilon$ for $n \ge n_0$. For $x = 1$ you get $|f_n(1)-f(1)| = 0$ for all $n
$.

Instead of considering real-valued functions you may consider the set $C([0,1],V)$ of continuous functions $f : [0,1] \to V$, where $V$ is a normed linear space with norm $\lVert - \rVert$. This induces again a supremum norm $\lVert - \rVert_\infty$ on $C([0,1],V)$. Pointwise convergence of a sequence $(f_n)$ means that $\lVert f_n(x) - f(x) \rVert \to 0$ for each $x$, but it is does not make sense to write $\lVert f_n(x) - f(x) \rVert_\infty$.

Comment: +1 for (4) :-).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 3)? Pointwise convergence is defined through the normed space's norm in the book that I am reading. I still don't get why "wrt the norm" would be rubbish, considering that the definition I have explicitly uses the norm of the normed linear function space.

Comment: I edited my post to be conformant to the guidelines that a user mentioned, and I added my thoughts at the end, could you elaborate on what I've mentioned at the end?

Comment: You are saying: "in fact you have $|x^n|=1$", but clearly the next line says for all $x \in [0,1)$, so actually $|x^n|<\epsilon$ for $n>N(\epsilon, x)$. And the distinction for the case $x=1$ is made after that. You say that it does not make sense to write $||f_n(x)-f(x)||_{\infty}$, but that $||f_n(x)-f(x)|| \rightarrow 0$ makes sense. So what if your normed linear space is endowed only with the $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm? I think that was the idea here. You are assuming your space is endowed with the norm $|\cdot|$ in your argument as far as I can see. Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Is the definition (2.3) of pointwise convergence in the book wrong? The definition clearly indicates that you should be using the norm of your normed space, I understand that in the sense that if your norm is $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ you should use it to check for pointwise convergence and not $|\cdot|$. Am I misunderstanding it, or is the definition wrong? In the latter case could you refer me to a text on functional analysis that treats this more robustly?

Comment: I have corrected an error in the answer (we do not have $\lvert x^n \rvert = 1$, but $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}{| x^n |} = 1$). The definition of pointwise convergence is correct, but the problem is this: You start with a norm on $V$ and then define the supremum norm on $C([0,1],V)$. This norm can only be applied to functions, it does not make any sense to write $\lVert f_n(x)-f(x)\rVert_\infty$ for a single point $x$. You **must not** confuse the norm on $V$ and the induced supremum norm on $C([0,1],V)$. This is what your book does. I believe **any** other book will do better.

Comment: Does $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|x^n|$ actually hold? You made this correction, but I am unsure whether it is actually correct. Since if you pick $x=1$, you get $|f_n(1)-f(1)|=0 \ne \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|x^n|$. The way I understand it is: $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|, x \in [0,1)\}  \ne \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|x^n|$.

Comment: Even with the edit to change $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$ I still believe that $\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|,x\in[0,1)\} \ne \sup\{|x^n|, x \in [0,1)\}$ since for $x=1$ the first evaluates to $0$, and the second to $1$, your term would be equivalent to $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|f_n(x)|$ and not $\sup_{x \in [0,1)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ I believe. Am I wrong?

Comment: See your question: The author says he computes $\lVert f_n(x)-f(x)\rVert_\infty$ for $x \in [0,1)$. He takes the sup over $[0,1)$ and not over $[0,1]$. In this range you have $f_n(x) - f(x) = x^n$. $x = 1$ is not contained.

Comment: Precisely - "in this range" - that is $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |x^n|$  for $ x \in [0,1) $, but you're writing $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \sup_{x \in [0,1)}|x^n|$ which is not equivalent I believe.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot explain it better. $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|} = |x^n|$ is wrong, the left hand side does no longer depend on $x$.  I am leaving the discussion now.

Comment: @lightxbulb, I guess that you have no problem accepting that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = x^n$ holds for $x \in [0, 1)$, where $f_n(x) = x^n$ and $f(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}(x)$ are as in Example 2.4. Then what hinders you from believing that taking supremum to the same set yields the same value? Two sets $$\{ |f_n(x) - f(x)| : x \in [0, 1)\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\{x^n : x\in[0,1)\}$$ are literally identical, so their supremum must equal as well.

Comment: @SangchulLee I guess my issue was that I didn't see them exactly as identical when it came to the supremum, since one evaluated to $0$ at $1$ and the other to $x^n$. Maybe my understanding of the supremum of a function was wrong. Thanks for clarifying it.